# How to do K-NN on Bag of words

Tags: python, text-mining

I have a training and test set (equal in size). I have done the bag of words model and I am trying to do K-nearest neighbor on it and I'm unsure how to do the fit.

Bag of words model:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
bow_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(max_features=100, stop_words='english')

bow = bow_vectorizer.fit(TrainData)
print(bow_vectorizer.vocabulary_)
bowTrain = bow_vectorizer.fit_transform(TrainData)
bowTest = bow_vectorizer.fit_transform(TestData)
```

Trying to do KNN on the Bag of Words model and I'm unsure what i'm supposed to put in the "knn.fit" portion

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 3)
knn.fit(bowTrain, ???? )
predict = knn.predict(bowTest[0:5000])
```

Comment: Why are you  building the learning model? What are you classifying?

Comment: well I am trying to do sentiment analysis (I have the labels for tweets (0 and 1))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
bow_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(max_features=100, stop_words='english')

X_train = TrainData
#y_train = your array of labels goes here
bowVect = bow_vectorizer.fit(X_train)
```

You should probably use the same vectorizer as there is a chance that the vocabluary may change.

```
bowTrain = bowVect.transform(X)
bowTest = bowVect.transform(TestData)

from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 3)
knn.fit(bowTrain, y_train )
predict = knn.predict(bowTest[0:5000])
```

Comment: oh I see, so I should take my training data (X_train) which has tweets/labels and just take the labels and put them into array y_train?

Comment: Yea your X_train should be tweets and y_train should be labels